# chrome.identity not showing all the logged in google account on popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth, google-oauth, google-signin, google-account

I am building an chrome extension in which I used

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
        interactive: true
    }, function(token) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            return;
        }
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + token);
        x.onload = function() {
            alert(x.response);
        };
        x.send();
    });
```

on background.js for google login authentication.

When this function called, a window appear which show logged-in google accounts (if any) but my problem is it shows only 1 account but I logged-in 5 accounts in the browser.

Is there anything which I missed over here ?

And I also need to know how to write logout function ?

Comment: There is only 1 account for Chrome, and that api only works with it.

Comment: Is there is a difference in between api which used for web application like stackoverflow and chrome extension ?

Answer (score 3):

`chrome.identity` will use the account that is "signed in" in `chrome://settings`. If not signed into Chrome, it will pop up a tab to allow you to "sign in" to Chrome, meaning linking the current profile and a google account.

If you want to show all the accounts simply signed in, you will need to manually create a popup window (using e.g. `chrome.tabs.create` or `window.open` and have the redirect url go back to your server which then communicates to your extension (e.g. using `sendMessage` and `onMessageExternal`), or if you have `tabs` permission, you could redirect using `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto` as your redirect url, which will make the oauth grant appear in the `window.title`, which you can read with your `tabs` permission.

Comment: Sounds good, but not understand properly what to do to create proper login using Google. Do you have any example or code login with Google on chrome extension ?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32548057/1236215 (the second part, where it uses chrome.tabs.onUpdated to look for window.title)

Comment: Thank you. This answer looks great, not tried yet but hope it will help me. What should I look for second part ? Is there something missing ?